# jQuery Mobile crash with other css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I want to use jQuery Mobile to make a persistent tab. But when I apply this to my view, it will destroy my page. I'm using CodeIgniter.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It will make my search column become like this:
[image: search column alterred]

When I open the side bar or click the link from the persistent bar to open another page, the page that I open will look like this:
[image: white page]

This is how i implement the jQuery Mobile in my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>home</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
        <!--theme-style-->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <!--//theme-style-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Food shop Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
        Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//fonts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/imgslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/slideout.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <h1 style="color:white">Menu</h1>
            <hr style="color:white;">
            <ul>

                <?php if($tipeUser=="user"){?>
                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_voucher/0" style="color:white">My Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/my_profile" style="color:white">Profile</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                        <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $rows->nama_jenis_makanan;?></a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq" style="color:white">Faq</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog" style="color:white">Blog</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser=="restoran"){ ?>

                    <li><h4 style="color:white">Welcome <?php echo $nama;?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/dashboard" style="color:white">Dashboard</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/voucher_management" style="color:white">Voucher Management</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                        <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $rows->nama_jenis_makanan;?></a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq" style="color:white">Faq</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog" style="color:white">Blog</a></h4></li>
                    <!-- <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/redeem_voucher" style="color:white">Reedem Voucher</a></h4></li> -->
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/logout" style="color:white">Logout</a></h4></li>
                    <?php } else if($tipeUser==""){  ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" style="color:white">Home</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" style="color:white">Login / Register</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher" style="color:white">Voucher</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_restoran" style="color:white">Restaurants</a></h4></li>
                        <?php
                        if($data_kategori->num_rows()>0)
                        {
                            foreach ($data_kategori->result() as $rows)
                            { ?>

                                <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Type/<?php echo $rows->id_jenis_makanan; ?>" style="color:white"><?php echo $rows->nama_jenis_makanan;?></a></h4></li>

                        <?php } } ?>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq" style="color:white">Faq</a></h4></li>
                    <li><h4><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog" style="color:white">Blog</a></h4></li>

                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main id="panel">
            <header><!--header-->
                <div class="header-in" >
                    <div class="container">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="header-bottom" >

                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <button class="toggle-button"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-11">
                                <?php echo form_open('home_controller/search_bar',array('method' => 'get'));?>
                                <div class="search">
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" id= "input-keyword" name="input-keyword" placeholder="Search ..." value="<?php echo set_value('input-keyword')?>" >
                                        <input type="submit" value="">  
                                    </form><?php echo form_close(); ?> 
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-role="content">
                    <?php 
                        if($dataSliderVoucher->num_rows()>0)
                        { ?>  
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <?php 
                                $i = 1;
                                foreach ($dataSliderVoucher->result() as $rowsSliderVoucher)
                                { 
                                    if($i==1)
                                    {
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Details/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>"><center><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>restaurant/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->gambar_voucher?>" height="200em" class="img-responsive" alt=""></center></a>
                                        </br>
                                        </br>
                                        </br>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h2><b><?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->nama_voucher?></b></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php }
                                    else
                                    { ?>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/Details/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>"><center><img src="<?php echo $url_image;?>restaurant/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->id_restoran?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->gambar_voucher?>" height="200em" class="img-responsive" alt=""></center></a>
                                        </br>
                                        </br>
                                        </br>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            <h2><b><?php echo $rowsSliderVoucher->nama_voucher?></b></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } 
                                $i++;} ?>
                        </div>

                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <!---->
                <div id="loader"></div>
                    <div id="scroll-container" class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="specials">
                            <?php if($dataLastDeals->num_rows()>0)
                                {
                                    foreach ($dataLastDeals->result() as $rowsLastDeals)
                                    { ?>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid black;">
                                    </br>
                                    </br>
                                            <?php if($tipeUser=="user" || $tipeUser==""){ ?>
                                                <div class="actions">
                                                    <?php 
                                                        if($rowsLastDeals->sisa_voucher > 0) {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <center>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/GetVoucher/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_voucher;?>">
                                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>.././img/restaurant/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_restoran;?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->gambar_voucher;?>" class="img-responsive-search" alt="" style="object-fit: fill;height: 250px; ">
                                                        </a></center>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                            <h3 style="font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><b><?php echo $rowsLastDeals->nama_restoran?></b></h3>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                            <h3 style="font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" align="center">Available <?php echo $rowsLastDeals->sisa_voucher. ' Voucher'?> </h3>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <?php
                                                        }
                                                        else{ ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>.././img/restaurant/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->id_restoran;?>/deals/<?php echo $rowsLastDeals->gambar_voucher;?>" class="img-responsive-search" alt="" style="object-fit: fill;height: 250px; ">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                            <h4 align="center" style="color:red; font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $rowsLastDeals->nama_restoran?> <br></h4>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                            <h4 align="center" style="color:red; font-size: 3vw;text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">NOT AVAILABLE <br></h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <?php }
                                                    ?>

                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>


                                        <!-- End Product -->
                                    </div>

                                <?php }} ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
            </header>
        </main>

        <?php $j=0; ?>
        <div id="pages">
        <?php  
         for($i=0; $i< $total_data; $i++)
        { 
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_Allpremium/<?php echo $j;?>"></a>
        <?php $j=$j+8; 
        } ?>
        </div>
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/" data-transition="pop">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/login" data-transition="pop">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/list_voucher">Voucher</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/faq">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home_controller/blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /footer --> 

    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) :     
    echo "<script>alert('". $this->session->flashdata('message')."')</script>";
    endif; ?>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/script.js"></script>
</body>



<script>


    var slideout = new Slideout({
        'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
        'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
        'padding': 190,
        'tolerance': 70
    });

    // Toggle button
    document.querySelector('.toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        slideout.toggle();
    });
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
    {
        slideout.disableTouch();

    }

    // auto close
    slideout.on('open', function() {
        $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
            return false; 
        });
        $( "#panel" ).click(function() {
            slideout.close();
        });
    });

    slideout.on('close', function() {
        $( "#panel" ).unbind('click');
    });


    </script>

    <script>
    $('.gallery').wmuSlider(); 

    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
        $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
    });
    // Update the contents of the toolbars
    $( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function() {
        // Each of the four pages in this demo has a data-title attribute
        // which value is equal to the text of the nav button
        // For example, on first page: <div data-role="page" data-title="Info">
        var current = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "title" );
        // Change the heading
        $( "[data-role='header'] h1" ).text( current );
        // Remove active class from nav buttons
        $( "[data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active" ).removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
        // Add active class to current nav button
        $( "[data-role='navbar'] a" ).each(function() {
            if ( $( this ).text() === current ) {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-btn-active" );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I had already searched for a solution. But I couldn't find anything. I had been struggling with this problem for weeks.

Comment: You could find which one of the those three scripts is responsible by removing each one of them and re-testing. If it's the css, try loading jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css before style.css. Also be aware that you are loading jquery twice. If you trim your php code and reproduce the issue in jsfiddle it will be much easier for us to help you out.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> ` This is the one that responsible for this problem. But if i remove this the persistent tab won't make the shape. It just will be plain text without any css. @R.Costa

Comment: Ok, but have you tried inserting <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4‌​.5.min.css"> before <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  as I suggested ?

Comment: yes i had. But nothing different. @R.Costa

Comment: Don't you have a live version of your website, so I could inspect your code ?

Comment: this is the link to my website live
`http://kupon-in.com/mobile/` But i haven't publish the one with the jquery mobile because this problem @R.Costa

Comment: The problem is that you are combining jQuery Mobile with Bootstrap - you must choose one of the frameworks since they are not compatible.

Comment: ok thx for your info and your help. @R.Costa